# How do I call a controller action from within my view using Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 2 Controllers

```
- HomeController
    - Index()
- AccountController
    - Login()
```

In my Home/Index.cshtml I want to Load The AccountController/Login method which then returns a view and displays it in my Home/Index view.

**Home/Index.cshtml**

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- Render the view that the AccountController/Login method denotes -->
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

use this with your actual Controller/View names

```
@Html.Partial("../Home/Login", model)
```

or

```
@Html.Action("action", "controller", parameters)
```

Comment: Thanks man! Is there a list of these methods for me in the future to check upon? :)

Comment: look at MSDN here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper(v=vs.108).aspx :)

Comment: You should prefer using `Html.RenderAction` and `Html.RenderPartial`, respectively, to improve performance over `Html.Action` and `Html.Partial`.  `Html.Partial` and `Html.Action` allow you to capture the output, which happens rarely, whilst the other two write directly to the response stream.

Comment: Thanks John for the tip. Just got to suss out what to put in the second parameter.

Comment: @JohnH - when I use HTML.RenderAction( "Login", "Account" ) it throws an error even though one of the overloads takes a string for each parameter?

Comment: @JamesT Try: `@{ Html.RenderAction("Login", "Account"); }`

Comment: @wudzik - Is there a way to prevent the Layout being called when using Html.Action, I'm getting the wrapper twice on my site because of it :)

Comment: @JohnH CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult‌​)' has some invalid arguments - The AccountController has an ActionResult method called Login that takes one string parameter... (It's the default AccountController when you create a new MVC project)

Comment: @JamesT Sorry, I'm not in front of a compiler right now, but you can pass parameters like so: `@{ Html.RenderAction("Login", "Account", new { someParam = value }); }`

Comment: Nice one man, that was it.. so it was requiring the parameter :D You da man :)